# C++ string arrays and for loops. PlaySound

Tags: c++, arrays

I am somewhat new at coding, though I have completed some simple tasks and such. I am having trouble with this small project. I want to have the code do a `for` loop, searching through each element of the array, checking what character is in each. If the element is equal to a certain letter, it plays a sound file corresponding with that letter.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "winmm32.lib")
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{    
    string myArray[] = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"};
    for(int i = 0; i < (sizeof(myArray)/sizeof(*myArray));i++) {
            if(myArray[i].find("a")) {
            cout << myArray[i] << endl;
            PlaySound("C:\\Users\\victor.leese\\Desktop\\a.wav", NULL, SND_SYNC);

            }     

}
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

THe problem is, when I execute the code, and in the if statement, the element is i, it doesn't print "a", but prints the other 6 letters, and plays the A sound file that many times. THe way I understand it, and want it to work, is that it should only print "a" once, at the start, and only play the sound file once.

I realise there is probably a really simple solution or something I have forgotten. Thanks for any input.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is the problem with this code? What does/doesn't it do that you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this statement

```
if(myArray[i].find("a"))
```

to

```
if(myArray[i].find("a") != std::string::npos )
```

Comment: Yes problem is fixed. Thank you >:]